# How do you redirect to a new host and maintain the path information in your routes.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I ran into this issue and couldn't find a concise and beautiful solution for the configuration. **I would like to redirect all requests that match a specific pattern to another host and include any path provided in the request.**

```
http://host1.com/something           -> http://host2.com/something
http://host1.com/something/something -> http://host2.com/something/something
```

Answer (score 1):

This was the solution and I hope it saves someone time!

```
  get 'something(/*path)', to: redirect {|params, request| 'http://host2.com' + request.path}
```

Comment: You should probally solve this on the HTTP server layer (Apache or Nginx)  instead of in the rails app. The overhead is much smaller.